# Compartir contenido con redes sociales mediante enlace directo

Tags: html, facebook

Necesito saber cuál es el formato correcto para compartir la página web mediante enlace directo.

He encontrado el siguiente formato para compartir enlaces en Facebook:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[ENLACE]
&picture=[URL DE LA IMAGEN]
&title=[TITULO]
&description[DESCRIPCION]
```

He investigado y encontré formatos generales y sus respectivos atributos pero no se encuentran todas las etiquetas disponibles para el formato.

En google sólo encontré el formato para compartir el enlace:
    https://plus.google.com/share?url=[ENLACE]

Para Twitter quiero saber como compartir una imagen.

Pero me gustaría saber cuales son los valores para añadir una imagen, ponerle el titulo y la descripción.

Me interesa poder hacerlo sin tener que usar meta tags, pues considero que son innecesarias.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta es cuales son los valores para una url compartir de google+ s y Twitter?

Comment: Nota: en el caso de Twitter, se puede dar el caso en el que se permitan más de 140 caracteres si hay una URL porque se transformaría con su acortador de URLs

Comment: Para facebook aquí está explicado: [http://marcodetrabajo.com/configura-web-imagen-compartir-facebook/](http://marcodetrabajo.com/configura-web-imagen-compartir-facebook/)

Answer (score 4):

Para `twitter` puedes usar:

```
http://twitter.com/share?url=[url]&via=trucsweb&image-src=[img]&text=[title964]
```

En la documentación podrás ver todos los [parámetros](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/parameters)

Mientras que para `google+` según la [documentación](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#share-link) solo soporta dos parámetros: `url` y `hl` (ve la parte de Share Endpoint) ahí si tendrías que buscar otr método para compartir

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que solo tienes duda en `Twitter`, que esta sería la forma de compartir :

http://twitter.com/share?**url**=URL_PAGINA&**text**=MENSAJE

donde los parámetros son:

> **url**: La URL de la página para compartir.
>
> **text**: El texto del mensaje.

#### Es importante considerar que el texto (considerando también la url), únicamente puede contener 140 caracteres, si envías más que esta longitud, no se realizara el post correctamente, y obtendrías el mensaje:

> Your Tweet was over 140 characters. You'll have to be more clever.

En [`Google +`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/) que se realizaría de esta forma:

https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?**hl**=es&**url**=URL_PAGINA

donde los parámetros son:

> **url**: La URL de la página para compartir. Este valor debe ser URL codificada.
>
> **hl**: El [código de idioma](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#language-codes).

Answer (score -1):

Para facebook aquí está explicado: http://marcodetrabajo.com/configura-web-imagen-compartir-facebook/

El método actual y correcto de indicar qué imagen ha de mostrar facebook cuando queremos compartir, es la utilización de unos meta tags que proporciona el protocolo Open Graph para integrar páginas en las redes sociales, más en concreto, en el llamado Social Graph.

Los meta tags que utilizaremos y colocaremos en el “head” del HTML, son los siguientes:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Título de página" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Descripción de página" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://midominio/imagen.jpg" />      
<meta property="og:url" content="http://midominio" />
```

En el primero (image), indicamos la imagen que queremos que aparezca en facebook. Es posible poner varias imagenes y seleccionar una en el momento de compartir, para ello basta con repetir el primer meta tag con varias imágenes. Los demás también son útiles y aportan más información a la persona que ve la web compartida. Y también hay más, lo cuales se pueden consultar en la guía de referencia.